# How to fix transparency problem?

Tags: transparency

[image]

I'm currently watching CG Geek's VFX tutorial and in his video, there is no transparency box around the subject but I do. How do I fix it? Much appreciated!

Comment: It should be a png file! How you are adding the image to viewport? Are you using `Images as planes` addon?

Comment: Yep it is a png file and I added it using "Images as planes". I followed exactly everything from his video. I'm stuck here and it's so frustrating :/

Comment: Can you provide video link?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ZpGpfQjzJA&t=1246s

Comment: Okay, it is all same! Can you share blend file?

Comment: From where did you got that png file?

Comment: I downloaded it from his youtube video description. I'm using cycles and in look dev mode, the transparency box is gone but in rendered mode, it's there. This is weird lol

Comment: can you share your blend file?